# Why is my cart empty after I click on the "add to cart" button?

Tags: 7, ubercart, ssl

I'm trying to use the [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module in conjunction with Ubercart. The module works fine for the most part. However, there is something wrong with the https that prevents an item from going into my cart the first time. Here is my problem in detail:

1. Start on a product page which is not using https.
2. Click on the "add to cart" button. I am redirected to https://www.example.com/cart. My cart is **empty**.
3. Navigate to any other "unsecured" page, like the product page I came from. **I receive a message stating that my item was added to my cart.**
4. Go back to https://www.example.com/cart and **I find an item in the cart.**
5. Resume shopping as normal without any further problems.

What is happening in step 2? Why is my item not added to the cart until I go to a different page first? Its worth noting that no errors were reported either in watchdog or other system logs.

I attempted to fix this problem by removing the **cart** page from the secure pages list. Is there a reason the cart page should be using https?

Additional notes:

- The old D6 / UC v.2 version of my site w/ Secure Pages worked without any problems.
- I have added **$conf['https'] = TRUE** to my settings.php
- Refreshing the cart page immediately after completing step 2 does **not** show any items in my cart.

Comment: The session is not being shared between http and https, it might be worth trying `$cookie_domain = '.example.com';` in `settings.php` in case it's a subdomain issue like `http://example.com` going to `http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in drupal 7. I disabled secure pages module and used .htaccess file for https stuffs.

Comment: I ended up making the whole site served under https and disabling secure pages